# Defining a public method in a Ruby module?

Tags: ruby

I must be making a n00b mistake here.  I've written the following Ruby code:

```
module Foo
   def bar(number)
      return number.to_s()
   end
end
puts Foo.bar(1)
```

test.rb:6:in `<main>': undefined method`bar' for Foo:Module (NoMethodError)

I wish to define a single method on a module called Foo.bar.  However, when I try to run the code, I get an undefined method error.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are defining a 'instance' method(it really is just a wild method encased within a module) and then trying to call it as if it was a 'class' method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could do with:

```
module Foo
   def self.bar(number)
      number.to_s
   end
end
puts Foo.bar(1)
```

Comment: Thanks!  Any idea why it doesn't appear this way in the example at the top of this page: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Module.html

Comment: It appears exactly this way at the top of that page. Maybe you are confusing an instance method with a class method?

Answer (score 5):

Every module in Ruby can be mixed in an object. Once a class **is an object**, you could mix the methods in a class using the word *extend*:

```
module Foo
  def bar
    'bar'
  end
end

class MyInstanceMethods
   include Foo
end

class MyClassMethods
   extend Foo
end

## Usage:
MyInstanceMethods.new.bar
=> "bar"

MyClassMethods.bar
=> "bar"
```

If you wish calling the bar method directly from the Foo module, you could do in the same way @xdazz wrote, but since the *extend* word mixes to a Class:

```
MyInstanceMethods.class
=> Class

MyClassMethods.class
=> Class

Module.class
=> Class # Hey, module is also a class!!!!!
```

The trick:

```
module Foo
  extend self # self of Foo is the Module!

  def bar
    # .....
  end
end
```

Now you can see **Foo.bar** returning the expected result :P